# GET http://localhost:8000/album/songs/undefined

Tags: jquery, html, arrays, json, undefined

Kindly assist in solving this, I'm just trying out using HTML5 media player, it's been smooth and steady until now when I try calling pulling music from the source folder and its displays this error on the console. I am using UCBrowser.

```
var b = document.documentElement;
var tracks;
b.setAttribute('data-useragent', navigator.userAgent);
b.setAttribute('data-platform', navigator.platform);


// HTML5 audio player + playlist controls...
// Inspiration: http://jonhall.info/how_to/create_a_playlist_for_html5_audio
// Mythium Archive: https://archive.org/details/mythium/

$(document).ready(function(){

    $.ajax({
        type: "get",
        url: "{!! URL::to('playSongs') !!}",
        success: function(data){
            tracks = data;
            actionAudio();
        }
    });

function actionAudio(){
jQuery(function ($) {
    var canvas, ctx, grd, source, context, analyser, fbc_array, bars, bar_x, bar_width, bar_height;
    var supportsAudio = !!document.createElement('audio').canPlayType;
    if (supportsAudio) {
        var index = 0,
            playing = false,
           // mediaPath = '//archive.org/download/mythium/',
            mediaPath = '/album/songs/',
            extension = '',
            trackCount = tracks.length,
            npAction = $('#npAction'),
            npTitle = $('#npTitle'),
            audio = $('#audio1').bind('play', function () {
                playing = true;
                npAction.text('Now Playing...');
            }).bind('pause', function () {
                playing = false;
                npAction.text('Paused...');
            }).bind('ended', function () {
                npAction.text('Paused...');
                if ((index + 1) < trackCount) {
                    index++;
                    loadTrack(index);
                    audio.play();
                } else {
                    audio.pause();
                    index = 0;
                    loadTrack(index);
                }
            }).get(0),
            btnPrev = $('#btnPrev').click(function () {
                if ((index - 1) > -1) {
                    index--;
                    loadTrack(index);
                    if (playing) {
                        audio.play();
                    }
                } else {
                    audio.pause();
                    index = 0;
                    loadTrack(index);
                }
            }),
            btnNext = $('#btnNext').click(function () {
                if ((index + 1) < trackCount) {
                    index++;
                    loadTrack(index);
                    if (playing) {
                        audio.play();
                    }
                } else {
                    audio.pause();
                    index = 0;
                    loadTrack(index);
                }
            }),
            li = $('#plList li').click(function () {
                var id = parseInt($(this).index());
                if (id !== index) {
                    playTrack(id);
                }
            }),
            loadTrack = function (id) {
                $('.plSel').removeClass('plSel');
                $('#plList li:eq(' + id + ')').addClass('plSel');
                npTitle.text(tracks[id].name);
                index = id;
                audio.src = mediaPath + tracks[id].file; // + extension;
            },
            playTrack = function (id) {
                loadTrack(id);
                audio.play();
            };
        //extension = audio.canPlayType('audio/mpeg') ? '.mp3' : audio.canPlayType('audio/ogg') ? '.ogg' : '';
        loadTrack(index);
        window.addEventListener("load", initMP3Player(audio), false);
        audio.crossOrigin = "anonymous";
    }
});
}
});
```

Error on the console:

```
GET http://localhost:8000/album/songs/undefined
```

I don't know the reason why its appending undefined to the URL. Normal URL ought to be http://localhost:8000/album/songs/song_name.mp3

Comment: It seems like the song_name is not calculated correctly. You might want to debug and see what value to do you get for that.

Comment: I don't know what you mean: "not calculated correctly". Please help.

Comment: url: "{!! URL::to('playSongs') !!}", <-- What is this?

Comment: @Kodos Johnson, could yo help with the snippet? Appreciate.

Comment: @sergio0983, I'm using Larave-5.3 with it. That's Laravel-blade syntax

Comment: So what does the AJAX return. What is `data`. `console.log(data)` and tell us.

Comment: It returns the object data from db: ```Object
albums_id
:
9
created_at
:
"2016-11-03 13:57:40"
file_mime
:
"image/jpeg"
file_name
:
"581b4254196ae0e736dcd2b012178be5e12b95827c31f[1].jpg"
file_path
:
"album/songs581b4254196ae0e736dcd2b012178be5e12b95827c31f[1].jpg"
file_size
:
"5488"
id
:
29
updated_at
:
"2016-11-03 13:57:40"
user_id
:
1```

Comment: So it looks like an object instead of an Array, and you also don't have a `file` key.

Comment: It's an array of objects, I only posted one of the objects it returned.

Comment: Ok, but you still don't have a `file` key. Unless you haven't posted that.

Comment: Thanks @putvande it returns objects not array, how do I make it return array?